# A C function pointer cannot be formed from a closure that captures generic parameters

Tags: objective-c, swift, generics

I need to create [IOServiceMatchingCallback](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/iokit/ioservicematchingcallback) to detect my USB device, but when i do this:

```
public class myMonitor<T:myDevice>: NSObject {
    function initUsb() {
         let removalCallback: IOServiceMatchingCallback = {
                (userData, iterator) in
                let this = Unmanaged<myMonitor>
                    .fromOpaque(userData!).takeUnretainedValue()
                this.rawDeviceRemoved(iterator: iterator)
            }
    }

}
```

Compiler says:

> A C function pointer cannot be formed from a closure that captures
>   generic parameters

When i used non generic class it worked fine. How to pass generic object to `Unmanaged`  ??

Comment: I strongly assume this cannot work with a generic class. The callback is a pure C function and cannot depend on (or use) the type placeholder `T`.

Comment: :( any recommendations ?

Comment: Put the code in a separate (non-generic) class, and add an instance pointer to that class as property to your generic class.